# POSIX behavior of sed's ^ and $ regex anchors with multiline pattern spaces

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, posix

What is the POSIX behavior of the `sed` `^` and `$` anchors when used at the beginning and end of a regex if the pattern space contains embedded newlines, like after you use the *N* command?

Should they still match the beginning and end of the pattern space or should they match the beginning and end of any line now that it contains multiple lines?

GNU `sed`'s `^` and `$` still match only the beginning and end of the entire pattern space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` and `$` in [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) always match at the start and end of *line*, as describe [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08).

Any `sed` which use [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) will do the same way. In case of using `N` command, `sed` saw multi lines as one long line in pattern space, with each *real* line separated by embedded newline `\n` (literal `\` and `n`).

For confirmation:

```
printf '1\n2\n' | sed '1N;/2$/d'
```

output nothing. And:

```
printf '1\n2\n' | sed '1N;/1$/d'
```

gave you:

```
1
2
```

Or using `l`ook command for more verbose:

```
$ printf '1\n2\n' | sed 1N\;l
1\n2$
1
2

$ printf '1\n2\n' | sed 1N\;l | od -t a
0000000   1   \   n   2   $  nl   1  nl   2  nl
0000012
```

Comment: IMO, the [spec has a bug](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=976) at the link you're giving here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Yeap, I also questioned about that. I'm looking for definition of what *line* mean in spec.

Comment: @cuonglm this is why I asked the question. I read one thing that suggested sed anchors behaved like Python's in MULTILINE mode, but they clearly don't, so I looked at the spec but couldn't figure it out

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: `perldoc perlre` seems to be more obvious in this case, since when it also use the term `string` for `^` and `$` by default, and define `string` is one `line` only.

Comment: @user129102: Can you give the link gave you the suggestion? `sed` anchors behaved like Python re without MULTILINE mode.

Comment: P. 30 from the Sed & Awk book by Dougherty & Robbins

Comment: @user129102: I don't find anything related in page 30, but this sentence is from **6.1.1** `In a multiline pattern space, the metacharacter "^" matches the very first
character of the pattern space, and not the character(s) following any embedded newline(s). Similarly,
"$" matches only the final newline in the pattern space, and not any embedded newline(s)`